# boost::format form c-string or std::string

Tags: c++, boost, string-formatting, stringstream, stdstring

How can i create a `boost::format` type formatter object using the character-string or `std::string`.
Trying to use following code which doesn't run. Want to achieve code equivalent to following code (semantically):

```
    format fobj("first-> %1% , second-> %2%");
    std::stringstream s;
    s<<fobj %1 %"%1%.";    //so that I can use s.str() to create a boost object
// How to create fmt object  HERE  
    ss<< fmt %"replacedtext";
    cout<<s.str()<<endl;
    cout<<ss.str();
```

Sample case:
**s** should be **"first-> 1 , second-> %1%."**
so that I can use this s.str() string to  create another format object fmt to which i can feed the substitution values.

Any thoughts folks??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you are trying to do, the [boost::format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) docs are a good place to start, there are a number of clear examples showing how to use the class.

You can create a formatter object and feed elements in via different operations (unlike say, printf where all params need to satisfy the `va_arg` you pass in).

```
boost::format fmter("%2% %1%");
fmter % 36; 
fmter % 77;
```

You can then obtain a string from the result.

```
std::string s  = fmter.str();
```

Be aware there are a [number of exceptions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/format/doc/format.html#exceptions) that can be thrown.

If you are looking for something that dynamically creates a format string you can do that in any number of ways.

```
std::string strFormatString = "first-> %1% second-> %2%";
boost::format formatter( strFormatString.c_str() );
formatter % value1;
formatter % strFormatString.c_str();
boost::format secondFormatter( formatter.str() );  // etc etc etc
```

Comment: the objective is exactly opposite to what you have written :)
what you have written is   
std::string s  = fmter.str();  
which semantically says get the string from  the formatter.
What I meant symantecally was get a formatter from the string. The string could be from the formatter or something else

Comment: It seems boost::format example does not work in the line " s= str( format(" %d %d ") % 11 % 22 )" at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/format/example/sample_formats.cpp . boost::format(...).str() should be called. Or I missed anything?